# Zimbra Java configuration to send email and loggging

Tags: java, logging, soap, email-client, zimbra

I am looking for code that allow me to send email via java to zimbra Soap API.

My initial though is to use apache-cxf and convert wsdl file into java files. I am able to do that. Now, I have corresponding functions are available as well.

Now, I want to send email using zimbra server. After searching over Internet, I still not able to find any article. 
I have also configured Zimbra server on one of my machine. How do I configure to use that machine ip address or domain to send email via zimbra soap api?

Can anyone guide me how to send an email using java to Zimbra server? What else I need to do to get logs of email? e.g, I want logs regarding email delivery, weather it get delivered, deffered, or bounce backed?

Any api is available to get this logs? Or is there any physical location where zimbra write the logs?

I have also looked at Rest api, however It was not useful either. I am using ZCS 8.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

> What else I need to do to get logs of email? e.g, I want logs regarding email delivery, weather it get delivered, deffered, or bounce backed?

Found under /var/log/zimbra.log.

For further details please see; http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Ajcody-Logging#The_Bread_And_Butter_Logs

There is plenty information on ZCS 8.0.7 including admin guides/release notes as well as the zimbra wikis/forums.

Comment: I know zimbra.log shows status of an email. But in order to find specific status of an email, I need identifier that being generated by zimbra. In order to get that identifier, I probably need to use soap api. I have done some progress. I will update the post as soon as, I will find some more information.